# SELECT из базы mysql с сортировкой по условию

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

подскажите как решить такую задачу:
Есть таблица базы данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли возможность создать запрос, чтобы получить выборку в следующей сортировке:
Сначала все где time больше 0 в порядке возрастания, потом все что равны 0, потом все что меньше 0(в такой: 110,105,104,102,0,0,95,92).

Спасибо

Comment: *Сначала все где time больше 0 в порядке возрастания, потом все что равны 0, потом все что меньше 0(в такой: 110,105,104,102,0,0,95,92)* 110,105,104,102 - это в порядке возрастания? 95 и 92 - это меньше 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подозреваю, что имелось в виду таки не сравнение с нулем, а со 100. То есть сначала больше 100, потому нулевые, потом меньше 100.

Наверное, самым очевидным решением будет использовать `case` в сортировке, например, так:

```
ORDER BY (case when v = 0 then 100 else v end) DESC
```

либо вариация  в виде

```
ORDER BY (case when v > 100 then 1 when 0 then 2 else 3 end)
         , v DESC
```

в некоторых сценариях можно делать отдельные выборки вида

```
select *
FROM (
    select 1 as n, v FROM t WHERE v > 100
    UNION ALL
    select 2 as n, v FROM t WHERE v = 0
    ....
) AS x
ORDER BY n, v
```

Comment: В поле time проставляется дата(unixtime) до начала события, и сравнивать буду с текущим timestamp/ Поэтому, сначала нужно вывести те которые больше текущего времени, потом те у которых по каким-то причинам не проставлена дата(0), а потом те у которых прошли

Comment: ORDER BY (case when v = 0 then 100 else v end) DESC - Это сработало, Спасибо большое